# How to display font familly on jetpack compose preview

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I display font familly on jetpack compose preview ?

I have my font in path : `res/font` resource directory as `.ttf` type on  then I'm using `MaterialTheme.typography` theme file to display them.. on emulator only.

[image: ScreenShot]

There is my `Theme.kt`:

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Green,
    secondary = Blue,
    background = Dark
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Green,
    secondary = Blue,
    background = Dark
)
```

```
@Composable
fun NutriGoodTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val colors =
        if (darkTheme) DarkColorPalette
        else LightColorPalette

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalSpacing provides Spacing()) {

        MaterialTheme(
            colors = colors,
            typography = Typography,
            shapes = Shapes,
            content = content
        )
    }

}
```

Then there is my `Type.kt` file:

```
val Typography = Typography(
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = PoppinsFont,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 14.sp,
        color = GreyMediumDark
    ),  
    body2 = ...
)

val Typography.textInput: TextStyle
    @Composable @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = PoppinsFont,
        color = GreyVeryLight,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 15.sp
    )
```

Comment: What is the name of your theme in your `Theme.kt` file? You use that theme inside the `@Preview` composable to get the same theme in previews. Please add both `Theme.kt` and `Type.kt` (or code where you have your typography defined) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

After being stuck on this problem for an hour or two and banging my head once or twice, The solution turned out stupidly simple

the reply above already mentioned it but since you didn't include your mainAcitivty file ill have to give simple code examples

when you make a project your MainActivity function will looke something like this

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            'YourAppName'Theme {
                some default code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `'YourAppName'Theme` is what applies the fontStyling but I and probably you deleted it from the DefaultPreview function since I dont use a theme usually and didn't add it all together in other UI composable functions..
anyway when you creat a new composable function, lets say

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ShowText(){
    Text("This is an example text",style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1)
}
```

and try to preview it, the "This is an example text" won't have the theme style applied to it instead you have to wrap it in a theme block, aka

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ShowText(){
    'YourAppName'Theme {
        Text("This is an example text",style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1)
    }
}
```

now the Text will have the custom font and wtver you want applied to it in the preview and do the same way in the default preview function if you want to preview everything

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    'YourAppName'Theme { //<- important!
        code you want to preview 
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes, the application theme looks not applied event I put it my MainActivity class.
But adding this one on the preview composable solve the issue. Thank for you response.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue on windows Android Studio, cause it's working perfectly on my macOs machine.