# Jetpack compose previews not showing custom Typeface (Material3)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I can see my theme custom typefaces correctly when running my app but not on my previews.

I'm already wrapping my preview component inside my custom theme `Composable` like this.-

```
@Preview(
    showBackground = true,
    widthDp = 480,
    heightDp = 960,
)
@Composable
fun PreviewAccessResultScreen() {
    CustomTheme {
        TestScreen()
    }
}
```

Which according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73423742/how-to-display-font-familly-on-jetpack-compose-preview) should do the trick (and totally makes sense to me).

*Any idea of what might I be missing?*